# Use WooCommerece or any other e-commerce plug-ins without products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, payment, checkout

What I want to achieve is using WooCommerce without products, meaning the price will be calculated in code; Based on a few entries from the user, I'll get the price from an API, then I want to check out the user, add to cart, whatever. Can that be achieved using WooCommerce?

Simply put, add whatever price I want from code to the checkout without products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't sell nothing, there must be some product. But you can change the item price after you add it in the cart.
So you add a product with some price into the cart and then calculate the price using your api and parameters and update the item in the cart,not the product itself. This is for woocommerce.